# New AWS Amplify app (serverless) is returning 403 Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-amplify, serverless, access-denied

I've created a new aws Amplify serverless (lambda) app using nodejs, expressjs and ejs and deployed it to the server (using auto deployment).  However, when I put the following url in the browser I received an error:
master.<...>.amplifyapp.com/staging/<...>

I get an access denied message as follows:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DD38C7RJ1EG7JCJS</RequestId>
<HostId>vyWlEWLC2Wv415/OjzDgu6Tk5udMxLi4sUTP9uUCBfDqkXMxOFKrJV9lYwSfCQCcrGRYgbT25do=</HostId>
</Error>
```

After this failure, I created an Amplify Function url which successfully returned my ejs template from my endpoint:
https://<...>.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging/<...>

Obviously the app is installed and working (because the Function URL is working) so I am at a loss why the other url does not work.  I have not created any authorization (anyone can hit the endpoint) and I chose to allow CORS.  What am I missing?

NOTE: this is a backend soltuion which use ejs for my template engine.  I don't have a frontend app per say (and, yes, I did add an index.html page just because others recommended it but that doesn't help). For my app, index.js is the entrypoint.

I can hit my endpoint using the Amplify Function URL (and receive back my ejs webpage) but I can't hit my endpoint using the amplifyapp.com url (which I need to work inorder to use a custom domain).

Answer (score 0):

You also can take a look if your IAM user has the AWSLambda_FullAccess and AdministratorAccess-Amplify permission

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Rosario.  I added those two rights to the IAM user, however, I'm still getting the same error.  Any additional suggestions?